# Como puedo validar, si el correo es del administrador, y redirigirlo a una ventana en especial

Tags: angular, firebase, typescript, ionic

Quiero que al momento de ingresar su correo, lo redirija una ventana específica, y cuando sea usuario normal a otra. ¿Como puedo realizarlo? 
Trabajo usando Angular, Ionic, y como base de datos FireBase[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes tener en tu respuesta el idPerfil, ejemplo:

idPerfil: 1
Perfil: Administrador

idPerfil: 2
Perfil: Usuario

Teniendo eso ya identificado seria algo como esto en tu código:

```
tryLogin(value){
    this.authService.doLogin(value).
        .then(res => {
            if(res.idPerfil===1){
                this.router.navigate(["/hom_admin"]);           
            }else{
                this.router.navigate(["/hom_user"]);
            }
            },err =>{
                this.errorMessage = err.message;
        })
}
```